# Create a G3 fax image with an ASN.1 wrapper for ldap photo

Tags: c#, image, ldap, asn.1

How can I create "An object encoded in G3 fax as explained in recommendation T.4, with an ASN.1 wrapper to make it compatible with an X.400 BodyPart as defined in X.420." in C#, starting from any standard .NET image/bitmap objects?

This is the LDAP definition of the [photo attribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms679116(VS.85).aspx).

Comment: Agreed.  Might as well be in Icelandic.

Comment: Say it ten times fast! She sells sea shells by the sea shore! (Geez that is even hard to type!!)  +1 for quality of the tongue twister!

Comment: Well first of all, you need to go through ADSI, which is the active directory API. To get it you need to download the Platform SDK, specifically for your platform. All the ADSI components are COM based, so if your doing it via C#, then I think it means COM interop. Their is a .NET Class System.DirectoryServices.dll which you can access. 

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/system/everythingInAD.aspx 

That will get you started. 

That will get you started. I can show you what classes to call to get access to the

Comment: Thanks for the reply but I think you've missed my problem: I use System.DirectoryServices quite a lot but I don't know how to convert a standard bitmap or jpeg photo into a G3 fax image with ASN.1 wrapper, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

G3 Fax is some version of TIFF if i remember correctly.

So you would probably have to encode some specific variant of TIFF in ASN.1 as described by that X.420 spec from the ITU (its freely available)

It states:

```
G3FacsimileBodyPart ::= SEQUENCE { parameters G3FacsimileParameters, 
                                   data       G3FacsimileData}
G3FacsimileParameters ::= SET { number-of-pages [0] INTEGER OPTIONAL, 
                                non-basic-parameters [1] G3FacsimileNonBasicParameters  
                                OPTIONAL}
G3FacsimileData ::= SEQUENCE OF BIT STRING
```

So, get some decent ASN.1 encoder and just dump a TIFF image in that format into the G3FacsimileData field and it should work.